# How to get vitest working with require of ES module

Tags: vite, commonjs, vitest, esmodules

Trying to migrate some old TypeScript code from CRA to Vite, and getting stuck on a problem with Vitest. The project has dependencies like this:

```txt
my-project (ESM)
  depends on: lib1 (CJS)
    depends on: lib2 (ESM)
```

The code seems fine at first glance, with `lib1` doing something seemingly innocuous like this in TypeScript:

```js
import * as lib2 from 'lib2'
```

Which transpiles to...

```js
const lib2_1 = require('lib2');
```

Since `lib2` is ESM, that, in principle, explains why Vitest errors out with:

```txt
Error: require() of ES Module /path/to/lib2/dist/esm/index.js from /path/to/lib1/dist/whatever.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /path/to/lib1/dist/whatever.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

HOWEVER, this surfaces only now, because both Vite and Webpack before it would simply do the right thing, as bundlers do, since of course `require()` doesn't even exist in the browser. Jest needed a little help, configuring `transformIgnorePatterns` to exclude `lib2` (i.e., allow transpiling `lib2` to CJS, which, for all its ugliness, allows everything to function).

Now, dynamic `import()` would break non-`async` callers, so eventually I'd like to migrate everything to ESM, but that will have to be a future endeavor. Meanwhile, I *should* be able to get Vite *and* Vitest to work with the code as is... right?

For reference, my `vite.config.cjs`, reduced to demonstrate the problem, is pretty simple:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('vitest/config');
const react = require('@vitejs/plugin-react').default;

module.exports = defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: { /* ... */ },
  test: {
    environment: 'happy-dom',
    globals: true,
  },
});
```

So, the question is: Since Vite is doing what's needed out-of-the-box to support `require` of ESM, how do I configure Vitest to follow suit?

Answer (score 0):

The thing I've found that seems to work, at least somewhat, is to configure:

```js
  test: {
    server: {
      deps: {
        inline: ['lib1'],
      },
    },
  },
```

Comment: ok this is part solution when one problem is solved and second appear. Now problem is to import unknown file with .css extension